# how to package hibernate-memcached to use it in JBoss 7

Tags: hibernate, module, memcached, jboss7.x

I have been trying to set up a Java EE Application on JBOSS AS 7 to use hibernate-memcached as a second level cache. The goal is to be able to scale at JPA level and to use a clustered cache. I've tried to manually put the jar in jboss modules but I am getting this errors.  here are some of those errors:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: could not instantiate CacheProvider [com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedCacheProvider]
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.<init>(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:68)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedCacheProvider from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @1839bb3 (roots: C:\jboss-7.0.0\modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:101)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186) [:1.7.0_03]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.<init>(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:65)
    ... 24 more
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways come to mind:

- Define a new hibernate-memcached module, and add a dependency to it in the main hibernate module; or
- just add the hibernate-memcached JARs to the main hibernate module and add them as resource-roots in `module.xml`.

For details on how to create and modify modules see the [documentation on class loading and modules in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7).